# Unfiltered html in widget title not working

Tags: widgets, filters, html

```
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    if( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) {
        $new_instance['title']     = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'], '<small><span><b><br><a><strong>' );
        $new_instance['more_text'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['more_text'], '<div><span><strong><b>' );
    } else {
        $new_instance['title']     = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $new_instance['more_text'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['more_text'] );
    }
[...]
```

I for sure am Admin i checked i can unfiltered html. But when i do this in my widget as seen in a tut its not working. Wordpress outputs it transformed into htmlspecialchars.

any filter for that? Hope its not a global filter i just wan't to do it in some widgets.

Whats the purpose of the sanitising in wigets then when wordpress runs it trough filters anyway?

After thinking about it i just will do this globally, i let wp do its thing and after that i just convert back what i need. Maybe a better solution then to remove the default esc_html filter and replace it with wp_kses and just allowing some tags. This way you still can see everything typed in and nothing is stripped out. Well at least not at that level. The widget itself might strip it or not.

```
/** allow <small> tags inside widget titles */
add_filter( 'widget_title', function($title) {
    $title = str_replace('&lt;small&gt;', '<small>', $title);
    $title = str_replace('&lt;/small&gt;', '</small>', $title);
    return $title;
} );
```

and the widget can now allow the tag or even everything, wordpress converts everything to htmlcharacters anyway. So only  will end up as real html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's outputting it transformed into htmlspecialchars you could just decode it.

In your widget() function:

```
echo $before_title;
echo htmlspecialchars_decode( $title );
echo $after_title;
```

Comment: Thanks i after thinking about it i just go with the global filter. Guess i asked to early. I digged into WP a little and its the esc_html filter applied to the widget titles by default. I edit my solution in and just accept this even if i would not recommend to do that, just letting **everything** come through.