# Allow different <span> tags in widget titles

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

How can I make widget titles allow HTML? I want to add icons from an iconfont to the titles like

```
<span class="icon-someicon">Widget Title Here</span>
```

I tried the following but it does not work at all...

```
function html_widget_title( $title ) {
    $title = str_replace( '[', '<', $title );
    $title = str_replace( '[/', '</', $title );

    $title = str_replace( 's]', 'span>', $title );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'html_widget_title' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoopsie, I found out how to do it - could not be any simpler. For additional information: I used fontello to create my own iconfont and added it to my WordPress Theme. That's why `font-family` is fontello in my snippet below.

I looked up the CSS Path to my widget titles (i.e. `.widget-3 > h3.widget-title`), added `:before` in CSS, looked up the icons (in this case \e805) in my fontello.css file and added the following CSS rules:

```
.widget-3 > h3.widget-title:before {
    content: '\e805';
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    font-family: "fontello";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what you are doing in the function. See below example how title can be wrapped in the html tag:

```
function html_widget_title( $title ) {
  $output = '<span class="icon-someicon">';
  $output .= $title;
  $output .= '</span>';
  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'html_widget_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the register sidebar array. You would need to repeat and change name/id and icon for additional widgets you need.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Widget Name',
    'id' => 'widget_name',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<span class="icon-someicon">',
    'after_title' => '</span>',
) );
```

If you need to be able to edit the HTML on every single widget title uniquely in the admin area, try the code you said didn't work. You would need to use it like a shortcode rather than HTML (it will parse as HTML).

So try doing `[span class="icon-iconname]Title[/span]`

See [Custom title widget / HTML encoding](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136788/custom-title-widget-html-encoding) for another alternative.

Comment: what does the code do - register new sidebars for each widget that I need to have an icon?

Comment: You've totally misread the question

Comment: I would say the question has not been fully clarified. Is this a point where you want to actually include it as a title in the widget menu?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me tested on WordPress 4.5.2

```
function nand_filter_widget_titles($title) {
    if ( $title != '') {
            $title = '<span class="icon-someicon">' . $title . '</span>';
    }

     return $title;
}
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'nand_filter_widget_titles' );
```