# Make forced line break in title of text widget

Tags: widget-text

I am using text widget in page, my title is too long and i want to make (Br)break in particular place, but i can not. After saving (br)break is gone, also tried (nbsp) but same result came. How to overcome?

Comment: May be this will help. [HTML is Widget title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136788/custom-title-widget-html-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around that by passing `widget_title` through a filter :

```
function custom_widget_title( $title ) {
    $title = str_replace( '__br__', '<br/>', $title );
    return $title;
}    
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'custom_widget_title' );
```

Now use `__br__` in your widget title instead of `<br/>` and the code will replace it.

**Note**: You need to put the code in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an HTML in the title. Leave the title empty and put the title as part of the HTML of the widget. Apply specific CSS to the widget to make it look like a normal text widget.

Comment: it's for client purpose. Client change it dynamically, so it has to be in title of text widget.

Comment: If you have additional constraints you should specify them in the question. Anyway I fail to see the contradiction, if a client knows enough HTML to use the text widget then it should not be a big problem for him to have the title as part of the text. Inserting <br> in the title also requires some knowledge of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Since `post_title` and `post_name` (url-part of the page) values  depends on each other I will not recommend you using HTML inside page titles. It may leads weird data generated

```
Title: "foo<br>bar"; 
Slug(URL): "/foobrbar";
```

, but you can create a `meta_field` to store HTML and output it.

1) Create a custom field `HTML_TITLE_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME` and fill in with your HTML title data;

2) Update your template files changing the title output logic as on example:

```
<?php
   $html_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, "HTML_TITLE_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME", true);
   if ($html_title) { ?>
      <h1><?php echo $html_title; ?></h1>
   <?php } else { ?>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```